# Using volume directory in build process

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to use mounted volume directory in build process, but it's either not being mounted at the moment or mounted incorrectly.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  assoi:
    restart: on-failure
    build:
        context: ./assoi
    expose:
        - "4129"
    links:
        - assoi-redis
        - assoi-postgres
        - assoi-mongo
        - assoi-rabbit
    volumes:
        - ./ugmk:/www
    command: pm2 start /www/ugmk.json
  ...
```

Dockerfile

```
...
WORKDIR /www
RUN ls -la
RUN npm i
RUN node install.js
...
```

`sudo docker-compose build` out

```
...
Step 12 : WORKDIR /www
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 73504ed64194
Step 13 : RUN ls -al
 ---> Running in 37bb9f70d4ac
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 22 13:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 65 root root 4096 Aug 22 14:05 ..
 ---> be1ac6edce56
...
```

Answer (score 1):

During build, you do not mount or more specifically, you cannot mount any volume.

What you do is COPY, so in your case

```
COPY ./ugmk /www
WORKDIR /www
RUN ls -la
RUN npm i
RUN node install.js
```

Volumes are for containers, not for images - volumes should store persistent user-generated data. By definition, this can only happen during the runtime, thus for "containers".

Nevertheless, the upper `COPY` is the default practice to what you want to achive "build a image with the application pre-deployed/assets compiled" ..